# gatsby-source-wordpress stuck on downloading remote files

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image, gatsby-plugin, wordpress-graphql

I am trying to build my project but using gatsby source wordpress plugin is taking a lot of time tom download remote files

````
success load gatsby config - 0.084s
success load plugins - 1.486s
success onPreInit - 0.006s
success initialize cache - 0.090s
success copy gatsby files - 0.282s
success Compiling Gatsby Functions - 0.362s
success onPreBootstrap - 0.413s
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  ensuring plugin requirements are met - 3.301s
⠀
info  gatsby-source-wordpress 

        This is either your first build or the cache was cleared.
        Please wait while your WordPress data is synced to your Gatsby cache.

        Maybe now's a good time to get up and stretch? :D

success  gatsby-source-wordpress  ingest WPGraphQL schema - 2.815s
success createSchemaCustomization - 6.167s
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  fetch root fields - 0.587s
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  Process - 14.431s - fetched 7
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  Category - 0.914s - fetched 8
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  Comment - 0.687s - fetched 0
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  ContentType - 1.116s - fetched 3
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  Faq - 55.839s - fetched 27
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  MenuItem - 0.643s - fetched 0
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  Menu - 0.836s - fetched 0
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  Oppturtunity - 10.024s - fetched 4
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  Page - 2.649s - fetched 1
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  PostFormat - 0.619s - fetched 0
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  Post - 19.927s - fetched 10
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  Project - 44.245s - fetched 23
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  Service - 6.152s - fetched 3
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  ServiceDetailPage - 35.901s - fetched 19
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  Tag - 0.724s - fetched 3
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  Taxonomy - 0.873s - fetched 3
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  Technology - 70.256s - fetched 36
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  TechnologyIcon - 18.546s - fetched 9
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  Testimonial - 9.993s - fetched 5
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  UserRole - 0.501s - fetched 0
success  gatsby-source-wordpress  User - 1.236s - fetched 2
⠦ source and transform nodes
⠴  gatsby-source-wordpress  fetching nodes — 174 total
⠋  gatsby-source-wordpress  creating nodes
⠋  gatsby-source-wordpress  MediaItem — fetched 11
[=========================   ]   157.275 s 10/11 91% Downloading remote files```


tried chnaging the configuration but no luck btw my current configuration settings
````

```
{
      resolve: `gatsby-source-wordpress`,
      options: {
        url: `http://localhost:10019/graphql`,
        develop: {
          hardCacheMediaFiles: true,
        },
        schema:{
          timeout: 12000000,
          perPage: 100, // currently set to 30
          requestConcurrency: 1,
        },
      },
    },
```

Comment: Ok its fixed now how to use the cached images with gatsbyImage Plugin?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.